Renaming the file caused the other file to disappear
I was wondering if theres anyway to recover my lost files. I was editing my public class constructor name in my file  A and I accidentally changed the constructor name to the same name as File B and it caused file A to replace file B. I recovered my file B but I lost all my previous work. Is there a way for me to recover my file B fuly?
I tried undoing the file but it didnt work

Do you have a JAR file of your project created earlier? If so, perhaps you can use a decompiler to retrieve your desired code. Something like Java Decompiler.

you can find the previous version of the file by the local history in vscode. Open the command panel and search for Local History: Find Entries to Restore. Look for the files you want to recover. Select the files you want to recover based on the most recent editing time.



